# Django 3.1.1 - changing password success but success page don't show

Tags: python, django, python-3.7

I config urls and add custom template (override registration/password_change_done.html and registration/password_change_form.html:) in my project but when I change password success the url have changed correctly (http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password/change/done/ url) but success page didn't show, it still shows the change password form. My code as below:

configuration urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns  = [
url('password/change/', 
        auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), 
        name='password_change'),
url('password/change/done/',
        auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), 
        name='password_change_done'),
url('password/reset/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset'),
url('password/reset/done/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset_done'),
url('password/reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset_confirm'),

url('password/reset/complete/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), 
        name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

password_change_done.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class='row'>
    <div class="col-12 text-center py-5">
            <h1 class='my-5 py-5'>Password successfully changed!</h1>
      </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

password_change_form.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-10  mx-auto'>
    <h1>Change your Password</h1>
        <form method='post' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
           {{ form.as_p }}
        <span style='margin-bottom: 12px;'></span>
        <button type="submit" class='btn btn-block btn-info'>Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show your views.py

Comment: I use default view (django/contrib/auth/views/PasswordChangeDoneView)

Comment: I think issue with myself. When I changed urlpatterns to path for a new version of django, the problem has been resolved. Thanks for help!